# Flutter how to draw marker based on list of object in TableCalender

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, calendar

I am using `TableCalendar` from `table_calendar` and I have a list of objects like below and wondering how can I draw markers based on the `dob` property to `TableCalendar`

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    DateTime dob;

    const Employee({required this.name, required this.dob, super.key});
}

var lEmpList = [
    Employee(name: 'John', dob: DateTime(1997, 8, 29)),
    Employee(name: 'Mary', dob: DateTime(1998, 11, 20)),
    Employee(name: 'June', dob: DateTime(2000, 11, 3)),
    Employee(name: 'David', dob: DateTime(1995, 10, 29)),
    Employee(name: 'Crown', dob: DateTime(1989, 8, 31)),
    Employee(name: 'Cindy', dob: DateTime(1990, 7, 9)),
    Employee(name: 'Jessica', dob: DateTime(1988, 6, 1)),
]
```

My expected outcome would be something like this: [image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at `CalendarBuilders` as described in the docs? Try that and give us an almost working code that we can help you fix?